# What happens in a clustered wicket environment when a model object is not serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, wicket

I'm seeing a NotSerializableException in the logs for a few of our model objects and I know that the fix for this is to make them serializable, but we are also seeing MarkupExceptions about components not being added to the page and I'm wondering if this could be related.  We're only seeing the errors in production where clustering is turned on.

So my question is, what happens when a model object is not serializable, even if all it's attributes are serializable?

Comment: `What happens` and `What happened when you try` should be in `HashMap`. Remove `serializable`  interface and try to make a request.Container confuses to read and write.

Comment: NotSerializableException appears when model objects are not detached (e.x. not attached to any component), so maybe you should try to detach the models first? I don't know any relation between NotSerializableException and components not being added to the page.

Comment: All I have to do is mark the model objects as serializable.  This has been done, but I am wondering what wicket actually does behind the scenes when these objects are not serializable.  I read that you can run into problems when using clustering, but I would like to know what these problems are and haven't been able to find much answers.

Comment: You have to be aware that some objects which are serializable may be wrapped in proxies (e.x. entities). This could lead to some inconsistent state (but this is only a guess) and bigger memory usage on the server side. IMHO the best you can do, is to check why the objects are not detached.

Comment: Does anyone know how this could lead to inconsistent state?  If this is the case, it could potentially create a markup exception in my case.  The model object is a list.  Another list determines the fragment to use (a 1, 2, 3, or 4 cell table row).  Then the model list is iterated over and each cell is added to the table row.  These two lists should have the same length, but if somehow the state is messed up one of the cells might not get added causing the markup exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you do not declare a class as serializable, then it will be missing from the serialized version on the subsequent actions (e.g. form submissions, behaviour, AJAX). Consequently, when the object is deserialized, it is likely that any object references will be null if child object cannot successfully be reloaded from the storage.

You should definitely avoid serializing objects unnecessarily. This includes in response to AJAX requests.

Best practices dictate:

1. Store only the minimum serialized objects required

   - Avoid declaring variables 'final' and referencing these from anonymous inner classes
   - Avoid having too many objects stored as fields in serialized objects (pages, panels or lists, etc)
2. Load objects for each request - especially model objects, which should be loaded from your data repository as each request is processed
3. Load your data objects outside of the constructor
4. Use models for all data, and attempt to mirror the Wicket structure for simplicity (e.g. using CompoundPropertyModel, where fields are loaded from the model object using reflection, based on the wicket:id used)
5. Use detachable models for any large objects that are loaded
6. Avoid using anonymous inner classes too much - use proper event handlers so your code is easier to read and maintain.

I have been working on a complex Wicket application for some time and I can tell you that you want to avoid duplicate objects appearing due to overuse of serialization / deserialization - it can be a nightmare to debug and fix.

Have a read of these for more information / suggestions:

http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/wicket-anti-patterns-avoiding-session-bloat/
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Best+Practices+and+Gotchas